# order of postgres placeholder

Tags: sql, c, libpq

I am using libpq to communicate with a postgres database. In postgres, when using the functions PQexecParams and PQprepare, placeholders may be used and one may bind to values via a const char pointer.

I am having issues finding a detailed explanation on this feature. E.g. consider a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4), ($1, $5, $3, $6), ($1, $7, $3, $8)
```

where $1 and $3 comes from a single value used in multiple rows, e.g. an int or a double and $2, $5, $7 stem from a collection like a vector and $6, $7, $8 from another collection.

Are the placeholders parsed on query execution to match the const char** offset or is this purely index based, i.e. index of placeholder matches the offset on the char** pointer? I.e., assume

```
const char** data
```

is passed into PQexecParams or PQprepare as the data argument. The following mapping valid:

```
data[0] -> $1
data[1] -> $2
data[3] -> $3
...
data[7] -> $8
```

Assume that I switch two placeholders in my statement. Say, I switch the first two placeholders:

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES ($2, $1, $3, $4), ($1, $5, $3, $6), ($1, $7, $3, $8)
```

Note that $2 now comes first and $1 second. When index-based, I expect the following mapping:

```
data[0] -> $2
data[1] -> $1
...
```

When parsed, I expect the original mapping to be still valid, i.e.

```
data[0] -> $1
data[1] -> $2
```

which one is true?

Comment: What does the documentation of the library say? What function are you using and what parameters it takes? What is the return value? This question requires much more focus

Comment: The placeholders are telling SQL where to get the value to replace them with. So `$1` always corresponds to `data[0]`, `$2` is `data[1]`, and so on.

Comment: @O________ AS clearly and accurately stated in the description, I am using PQexecParams from libpq. The official documentation of Said function does not elaborate on the behaviour. Which is the cause of this very focused question

Comment: @Barmar this sounds plausible, but I am looking for confirmation, which I could not find

Comment: The documentation simply says **If parameters are used, they are referred to in the command string as $1, $2, etc.**. I think you're expected to understand that the numbers correspond to indexes.

Comment: Precisely. That ist what the documentation Staates. For example, the SQLite documentation states: These expressions are parameters and a call to bind_... needs the index of the parameter AS argument. No ambiguity there. I did not find a correspondingly unambiguous explanation in the documentation for libpq. Hence this question. Your explanation seems likely, but database APIs do not necessarily behave similarly (neither does their SQL statements support). When implementing something for production, I would like to have clarity and confirmation, not makes-sense or likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is definitely something going on there that goes beyond counting placeholders and their positions: I have the following query to a table with two columns col1, col2:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2) VALUES ($1, $2);
```

This works with both postgres and sqlite. When I replace $2 with $4, it works find with sqlite, but I get an error message from libpq:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2) VALUES ($1, $4);
```

The error message being:

```
    Status code: 7
    error string: PGRES_FATAL_ERROR
    error message: ERROR:  could not determine data type of parameter $2
```